# How to best store and manipulate large datasets locally in a flutter app

Tags: database, flutter, hive

i´m currently building a Flutter app that includes a larger set of data (like 2000-10000 pieces of text).
I´m relatively new to Flutter delevopment so i have no idea what databases are the best for this case.

The app needs no connection to the internet a all data is on the device after downloading.
You only need to query this data extensively and build now datasets out of it.

I researched a bit, but the most common used database (hive) seems not to be suitable for my needs.

If anyone could help, I´d appreciate it.

Comment: Have you checked out the sqflite package? https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite

Comment: For records sake, a strong signal on Hive indeed not being suitable: https://github.com/hivedb/hive/issues/170

Answer (score 2):

*It seems ObjectBox is best For Large Data ,it Performs very Well*

```
[Check this package best suits for your data][1]
```

```
import 'package:objectbox/objectbox.dart';
```

````
class Note {
  // Each "Entity" needs a unique integer ID property.
  // Add `@Id()` annotation if its name isn't "id" (case insensitive).
  int id = 0;

  String? text;

  DateTime date;

  @Transient() // Make this field ignored, not stored in the database.
  int? notPersisted;

  // An empty default constructor is needed but you can use optional args.
  Note({this.text, DateTime? date}) : date = date ?? DateTime.now();

  // Note: just for logs in the examples below(), not needed by ObjectBox.
  toString() => 'Note{id: $id, text: $text}';
}```
````